# Creating a glue table with Core Data?

Tags: core-data, ios5

Let's say I had one entity called "Garage" and one entity called "Cars".

In SQL I might create a third table (sometimes called a glue table) that would just have two fields "GarageID" "CarID"

That way I could relate certain cars to certain garages.

How would this be handled with the Core Data modeller?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are talking about many-to-many relations. CoreData supports such model. Just create in both entities relations to each other set as "to-many". That's all.